# Switch resistor with n-channel MOSFET not working

Tags: transistors, npn, 5v, operational-amplifier

So I try to amplify a photodiode signal with an operational amplifier.

As I want to amplify two signals (1 for a high-intensity light and 1 for a low-intensity light) I sort of need to design a switch for the feedback line. Currently, I'm doing it manually, but that's not good solution. :-)

To demonstrate my idea I have made the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTdDWZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, I want to automatically be able to switch R1 to a lower resistor value (From 1MΩ to 180kΩ). 
 - I tried achieving it with the [2N7000](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF) Mosfet and an "extended" circuit, but for some reason, the transistor consumes a lot of the current.

What solution am I looking for here?

Comment: Google "analog switch".

Comment: I actually have a multiplexer laying around, thought that those only were for i2c signals?

Comment: @TimWescott https://dk.farnell.com/vishay/dg418dj-e3/ic-switch-spst-dip8-418/dp/1077114 -- Is this what you'd recommend me?

Comment: It depends on the multiplexer.  There are a lot of analog switches that are designed to be used in just the way you're contemplating.  Start with a 74LVC1G66 and work from there until you find the specifications you need.

Comment: The DG418 looks like it'd work.  It may be overkill, but it looks like you want a through-hole package and it'd certainly get the job done.

Comment: Great, thank you for your time and help @TimWescott - You can post it as an answer and i will accept it.